# Pasar datos de una consulta php a una tabla html

Tags: php, sql

Tengo lo siguiente:

**CODIGO**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container"  class="width">


    <article>
<h3>Empleados</h3>

            <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='600' bgcolor='#F6F6F6' bordercolor='#FFFFFF'>
<tr>
<td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Nombre</td>
<td width='50' style='font-weight: bold'>Numero de Empleado</td>
<td width='50' style='font-weight: bold'>NSS</td>
</tr>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("nomina");

$query = "select * from empleado"; // Esta linea hace la consulta
$result = mysqli_query($query);

while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
<tr><?php echo ?>
    <td><?php echo $fila['Nombre']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila['numemp']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila['nss']; ?></td>
<td width='150'></td>

</tr><?php echo ?>
<?php

?>
</table>
</article>
```

lo que sucede es que no logro que aparescan los datos , y sale la tabla en blanco , quisiera saber a razon del porque no salen, uso php 7 , gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas utilizando mysql, lo cuál está obsoleta en PHP 7, utiliza `mysqli_connect y mysqli_select_db`, te podrías ahorrar esta última función si en `mysqli_connect` agregas al ultimo el nombre de tu base de datos así: `$ con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'NombreBD');`, el siguiente error es de que estás imprimiendo `$fila` cuando la variable que estas declarando en el while es `$registro` y el otro error es que en la función `mysqli_query()` te falta agregar el otro parámetro, que es tu conexión, así `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);` .

```
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container"  class="width">


        <article>
    <h3>Empleados</h3>

                <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='600' bgcolor='#F6F6F6' bordercolor='#FFFFFF'>
    <tr>
    <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Nombre</td>
    <td width='50' style='font-weight: bold'>Numero de Empleado</td>
    <td width='50' style='font-weight: bold'>NSS</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "nomina");
    //mysqli_select_db("nomina"); ya no es necesario poner esta función.

    $query = "select * from empleado"; // Esta linea hace la consulta
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $registro ['Nombre']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $registro ['numemp']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $registro ['nss']; ?></td>
    <td width='150'></td>

    </tr>
    <?php
    }

mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    </table>
    </article>
```

No olvides cerrar tus conexiones con `mysqli_close($con);` cuando ya no vayas a utilizarla.

Comment: gracias por la asesoria, ya corregi los errores mencionados, pero aun no me sale nada , este es todo el codigo en general , ya no se que pueda ser

Comment: @romorroguzman que error se muestra en la pantalla?

Comment: me salen los encabezados de la tabla y abajo nada de informacion

Comment: Pero ningún mensaje de error?, estás seguro de que estás consultando bien la tabla y que haya datos en la tabla?

Comment: si hago la consulta desde un archivo php me corre sin problema alguno , aparecen los registros , lo que no entiendo es porque no me salen desde un archivo html que es donde he incrustado el codigo php que tu amablemente me corregiste

Comment: @romorroguzman Tal vez sea por eso, tu archivo debe de tener la extensión .php, lo hermoso de php es que puedes combinar estructura html sin problemas, intenta haciendo eso.

Answer (score 0):

talvez hacer un

```
var_dump($registro);
```

pueda ayudarte a visualizar la informacion contenida en tu arreglo.
tambien desbes guardar tu archivo con la extension `.php`